# Can't download due to no storage. I have enough storage

Tags: internal-storage

I keep getting a error saying cannot download not enough space. But according to my phone I have 429MB and the file I want downloaded is only 40.08MB. I don't want to use my SD card because the file will be deleted later but, it's needed now. What should I do?

Comment: How much storage does your phone have?

Comment: Android considers a phone lacking storage if less than 10% of its total storage is free. Bring the value of stored materials off the trigger value of 10%. Plenty of questions here with answers about that to find.

Comment: That 429 mb is not all for the tangible storage of the phone. Some of those are for cache, system storage etc

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your permissions set for the app in which you are downloading from?! Sometimes you can't even save your settings if they can not write to the drive/device.